# StructureMap with my own attributes in C#

Tags: c#, attributes, structuremap, custom-attributes

I have an attribute that I have written that has a dependency on the Data Access Layer so I made a constructor that took the DAL class as a parameter (marked with `[DefaultConstructor]` and another, blank, constructor that is parameterless. When I call a method that depends on the attribute how do I make StructureMap inject the correct type?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: I've now worked out that this should be done using setter injection, the documentation I can find for StructureMap only references older versions whose methods are deprecated. How would I do it in the current release?

Comment: Not sure that attributes will work with Setter injection as they are created via reflection. If you have access to an IContainer and the instantiated attribute you could use the IContainer.BuildUp(object o)   method. http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/16/quot-buildup-quot-existing-objects-with-structuremap.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on the same problem, i'm using something like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.PullConfigurationFromAppConfig = true;
    x.SetAllProperties(p => p.TypeMatches(t => 
        t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectAttribute), true).Length > 0));
}
```

I am having some issues injecting onto webform pages but it works when creating instances using ObjectFactory...

Comment: oh, the issues was resolved by having the InjectAttribute inherit from  StructureMap.Attributes.SetterPropertyAttribute